# Arabic Rendering in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, rendering, arabic

I have a flex 3 application compiled against Flex 3.5 SDK and I'm trying to add Arabic rendering support to it. The problem is that it renders Arabic from left to right while it is supposed to be from right to left and sometimes the sequencing of Arabic letters does not appear correctly while you are typing  (if a TextInput is inside a GridItem for example).

I have seen different libraries like Text Layout Framework and FlarabyFlex3 that display arabic correctly but my question is : do I have to replace all the controls in the code like (TextInput,TextArea,Label, Grids, etc...) and use TLE controls to fix this issue ?  isn't there a solution that I can apply once (like patching the sdk) to make all the controls render and display Arabic correctly without going through everyone of them ? because I can't go through changing all the controls since I have like hundreds of pages and controls  ..

Your help is much appreciated .. thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Flaraby uses classic text fields. But you *will* have to apply changes to all of your text fields, if you are going to provide both arabic and non-arabic versions of your application.  I myself have had a project like that, and ended up extending the TextField class, included functionality that will be able to swap arabic/non-arabic at runtime, and used that class instead of the native TextField. Also, dealing with input text is far more complicated, and you'll have a fun time trying to have more than one TextFormat per text field...

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. does that also apply to Text Layout Framework ? do I still have to go through all of the controls and replace them with the extended one ? is it a trivial task or a real pain ?

Comment: Also would that apply to Label controls ? or is the problem only in TextInput fields ? I mean do I have to replace Label controls also to enable correct Arabic rendering ?

Comment: I don't know about that, since I've only used the AS version.  But perhaps you should just check the documentation http://www.arabicode.com/flarabyas3flex/main